# Does air travel in the same time over the top of the airfoil and along the bottom?

Tags: aerodynamics, lift

If we assume two particles of air arriving at the leading edge, one flowing over the airfoil, the other under the airfoil. Do they arrive at trailing edge at exactly the same time?

Comment: No they don't. See: [Nasa, incorrect theory #1](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/airplane/wrong1.html)

Comment: Probably a better answer, contains what @mins is referencing: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16193/how-do-wings-generate-lift

Comment: Also relevant: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/why-is-the-wrong-explanation-of-air-travels-a-longer-distance-and-creates-a-lif

Comment: Depends on whether the particle gets into the boundary layer or not. If it does it will be slowed down considerably, depending on how much time it spends there, and how close to the wing surface it gets.